# Advice on electronic circuit design for an agricultural machine

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, dc-motor, motor-controller

I’m working on a project which is technically working well but I have some problems on the electronic circuit.

This project is my first professional project after I graduate university so I have no experience with things like this.

I designed an agricultural machine. There are 2 separate 12V DC motors in it. One of these motors draws 14 amperes instantaneously and the other draws around 8 amperes.

I used a car radiator brushed fan D  motor as I needed large torque. When I talked to the manufacturer, they told me that they tested these products themselves with 13 volts, so I drive the motors with the highest voltage of 13.5 volts at the moment (there is no overheating.) I will use 4s-15p lithium battery as the machine will be used for 2 -3 hours. The problem is, as you know with lithium batteries, a 4s connected battery gets 4.2 * 4 = 16 volts when fully charged. This is a voltage that the manufacturer does not recommend.

I am currently using a voltage regulator between the battery and the motor while performing the tests.

Is it right for me to continue like this? What would your advice be?

I use this DC motor as I cannot find another brushed DC motor that provides this torque.

This is an image of the DC motor and how I used it in a blower fan:

[image]

Comment: What kind/capacity of lithium batteries are you using?

Comment: I would guess that a 13.5V motor is probably okay with 16 volts, if you drive it with PWM to control the speed.

Comment: @Damien I have used "panasonic sanyo ncr18650ga" 3000mAh battery.

Comment: @user253751 I couln't find higher voltage dc motor :(

Comment: You have to ask yourself if you are willing to risk your professional reputation and your career on some anonymous person saying "I would guess" and "is probably okay". This sounds like a pending disaster to me.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson heh, I didn't read that it was the person's first professional project. That is slightly concerning. This forum sees a lot of DIY and university level projects where that sort of guess is often okay.

Comment: What are you controlling the motor with? Switch or speed controller?

Comment: You realize that your run time is going to be a few minutes? Maybe 2-3

Comment: @ScienceGeyser I'm using just switch, turn on - turn off.

Comment: @Damien battery cappacity is 45ah

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using brushless motors. Brushless motors require motor controllers. The normal configuration for a system with brushless motors is a battery with a higher voltage and an electronic motor controller that controls the motors with an effective voltage that is lower than the battery voltage. If the motor speed does not need to be adjustable, the motor controller can be quite simple. Manufacturers are typically using brushless motors for new designs of portable equipment. Look for a piece of portable equipment that has a motor of the power level that you need and examine the design.

Comment: Fact that I want to use brushless motor but I could not find a brushless motor with the same specifications, so compulsorily I used brused motor. Aslo my torque requirement quite high, for example fan torque request 0.5 - 0.7Nm, blade(trimming) normal trimming 0.1 - 0.3 hard trimming 1.5 - 2 Nm torque(with gear). For this reason I coulnd't find wide voltage running motor.

Comment: If this is professional work, you should probably put more effort into finding the optimum motor. It is probably somewhere waiting for you fo find. You probably need to contact manufacturers to find exactly what you need. For many products, manufacturers design their own motors or work closely with a motor manufacturer to get the optimum motor.

Comment: Yes I am developing a professional product, If I can make the product a little more ready, I think I can go stronger with a good investor. Unfortunately, big producers do not want to meet with small entrepreneurs like me.I'll push it to the end.